# run command in custom shell instance inside bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script:
script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -n password
if [[ $password = $correct-password ]]; then
custom shell
else
exit
fi
```

Then, I have another script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo password | ./script
commands
```

I want the commands in the second script to run in my custom shell not bash but they just run in bash. I can't do any changes in my first script.
Instead of echo I have tried redirect password from file and here document "<<" still yeilds the same result.

Comment: It is a little unclear as to what you are asking ...  Instead of `echo password | ./script` which just runs this script as a stand alone, you want to pass in arguments .. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: The `if` statement in the first script is not valid syntax. `((` should be `[[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a here-doc, and put the password on the first line.

```
./script <<EOF
password
commands
EOF
```

When you use a pipe, the standard input of the script just comes from the pipe; anything after that line will be commands to the original shell once `./script` exits.